# nodeJs - obfuscate sequential ids

Tags: node.js, encryption, sequential

I generate user IDs in a sequential fashion. I would like to obfuscate them, to prevent the ability of figuring out the list of all userIds in my system. What is the recommended way?

Technically: I want to do a random one-to-one integer<->integer mapping.

Comment: In general, I'd use GUIDs instead, so people can not really guess other user-ids. In you particular case, you could encrypt the user-id using whatever (modern) algorithm to create random looking ids.

Comment: How many characters can there be in the obfuscated user id, and from what set of characters?

Comment: https://github.com/RonnieSan/HashIds

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Knuth's multiplicative method.
The [inthash](https://github.com/denostack/inthash) library implements this, and it's safe to use because you can generate randomized settings via CLI commands.

Here's an example of usage (from the README)

```js
const hasher = new Hasher({
  bits: 53, // Javascript, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
  prime: "6456111708547433", // Random Prime
  inverse: "3688000043513561", // Modular Inverse
  xor: "969402349590075", // Random n-bit xor mask
});

const encoded = hasher.encode(100); // result: 6432533451586367
const decoded = hasher.decode(encoded); // result: 100

// You can obfuscate predictable numbers like 'Auto Increment'!
hasher.encode(1); // 6085136369434450
hasher.encode(2); // 4132187376469225
hasher.encode(3); // 2180123214014976
hasher.encode(4); // 6982551782798239
hasher.encode(5); // 5030633649101110
hasher.encode(6); // 3077950944243277
hasher.encode(7); // 1125015438342116
```